# Initialise C++ base class without typing whole base class type twice

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, design-patterns

I'm looking for a C++ pattern or technique that avoids some code replication.

I utilize [empty base optimisation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo) for some algorithms.
When I inherit from a class that has verbose template arguments it is cumbersome to have to enter the same verbose type in the [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) and as the base of a class.

A contrived example:

```
template <uint32_t Port, uint32_t Pin>
class Pin;
```

-

```
template <typename T>
struct ActiveHigh;

template <uint32_t Port, uint32_t Pin>
struct ActiveHigh : Pin<Port, Pin> // <-- First entry.
{
    ActiveHigh() : Pin<Port, Pin>{ false } {} // <-- Duplicate entry.
};
```

I'm writing a C++ linter which has a certain feature which should really utilise [empty base optimisation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo). There are literally thousands of lines of duplicate entries due to this pattern.
Does anybody have a pattern that they use to overcome this code smell?

**Edit 1**

[This is what I have](https://godbolt.org/z/ciuxqf) so far, but its sort of bad having to write typename on every instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following workaround:

```cpp
template <uint32_t PortT,
          uint32_t PinT,
          typename ActualPin = Pin<PortT, PinT>>
struct ActiveHigh : ActualPin
{
    ActiveHigh() : ActualPin{ false } {}
};
```

Comment: I do that sometimes, good suggestion.
However, it doesn't work with variadic arguments and also doesn't work if you are using ActualPin to partially specialise the class ActiveHigh.

Comment: This is the problem with this pattern with partial specialisation https://godbolt.org/z/UY3by-

Comment: @DavidLedger ah I see. I will think about another approach but will leave this answer here just in case someone else thinks about the same solution I provided

Comment: Sure, I do like this pattern its the best I've found for some limited cases. This is the problem with variadic arguments https://godbolt.org/z/SUdsf7